# Look up an "App Bundle" from itunes.apple.com/lookup

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

You can use itunes.apple.com/lookup to find metadata about apps, but I can't figure out how to query for app bundles. How would you look up a bundle?

Comment: Do you want to query metadata of one specific app bundle. https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284910350 might work? Update: no it doesn't :(

Comment: Have you discovered any way to do this?

Comment: I am looking for the answer too.  Did you find the solution yet? would you please share it here if you figure out the way how to do it?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iTunes Search API doest not support "App Bundle" for now. A workaround is using App Store's API:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: AppStore/2.0 iOS/8.3 model/iPhone6,1 build/12F70 (6; dt:89)" 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app-bundle/id982287814'
```

Comment: for the future generations: pay attention to availability region. Here is US defined - if your app is not presented there you will have nothing in response.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean lookup by app bundle id, like this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.yelp.yelpiphone
```

Comment: Idk if down voting is necessary. as when I read it he appears he is looking for a way to get app meta data by bundle-id. Which is what I provided.

Comment: It's not about the BundleId. There are App bundles, that include several apps. They have a trackId that does not return results from the normal API

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My brain did not understand.